# Letter shadow and letter alignment problem

Tags: shadows, text-object

I got a job and I need to add shadow to the text as in the image. But there are two problems here:
1- The middle of the shadow is very dark, while the rest of it is darker. How can I set this? I want everything to be slightly blurred.
2- Another problem is that the letters of the font such as 'U, Ş, O' are lower than the other letters due to the typography rule. I align them all to give a shadow, but this time the bottom of the letters are cut off. Is there a way to get only the shadows of the letter? I used the transparent node, but this time it also affects the shadow.
[image]

I hope I could explain. Thanks[image]

[image: Text Node]